# C# OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, out-of-memory

I'm getting an out of memory exception on this loop...however, it never even reaches a second iteration. The date index is 0 when the exception is thrown.

```
<% int date = 0; %>
   <% while (date < Model.TimePeriod1.Count) { %>
      <tr>
         <% for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            { %>
               <td><%: Model.TimePeriod1[date] %></td>
                  date = date + 1;
                  <% } %>
      </tr>
   <% } %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `date = date + 1;` is html, not code; hence it never changes `date`, hence it fills the entire memory with the output-buffer for lots and lots and lots of `Model.TimePeriod1[0]`. Add a bee-sting after the `%></td>`:

```
  <tr>
     <% for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        { 
           %><td><%: Model.TimePeriod1[date] %></td><%
           date = date + 1;
        } %>
  </tr>
```